# Permutation equivariant Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, permutations, permutation-matrices

Im trying to find something out about the elements of permutation equivariant matrices. So matrices where if you switch somehting in your input vector the output switches as well.

e.g.

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 1\\
1 & 3
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
2\\
1 
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
7\\
5
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 1\\
1 & 3
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
2 
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
5\\
7
\end{pmatrix}
$$

So what i tried was to define it in the follwing way
$$
A 
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
\vec{x}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
A 
\cdot
\vec{x}
$$
for two dimensions. For 3 dimensions it would need to specify 3 equations i think
$$
A 
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
\vec{x}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
A 
\cdot
\vec{x}\\
A 
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
\vec{x}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
A 
\cdot
\vec{x}\\
A 
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
\vec{x}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
A 
\cdot
\vec{x}
$$
I tried to use this definition to find something out about the coefficients $a_{i,j}$ of $A$ and see if the need to fullfil some sort of equation or condition. To me it seems like the matrix needs to symmetrical in order for the permutation equivariance to work but i wasn't able do derive it from these defining equations.

Hopefully someone can give me some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You want to compute the set of matrices which commutes with every permutation matrix. Equivalently, you want to compute the endomorphism algebra of $k^n$ regarded as a [representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_representation) of the symmetric group $S_n$.

This can be done as follows. Over every field of characteristic zero, $k^n$ breaks up as an $S_n$-representation as a direct sum of the trivial representation, spanned by $(1, 1, \dots 1)$, together with an irreducible representation of dimension $n-1$ given by the "orthogonal complement," namely the subspace

$$\{ (x_1, \dots x_n) \in k^n : \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = 0 \}.$$

Write $V$ for this irreducible representation. This gives $\text{End}(k^n) \cong \text{End}(1) \times \text{End}(V)$. We have $\text{End}(1) \cong k$ but $\text{End}(V)$ is only a priori a division algebra (by [Schur's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_lemma)). However, $V$ is [absolutely irreducible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_irreducibility), meaning it is irreducible after passing to the algebraic closure, and this implies (and is equivalent to) $\text{End}(V) \cong k$.

Altogether we get that $\text{End}(k^n) \cong k \times k$. Explicitly, there is a $2$-dimensional vector space of matrices commuting with every permutation matrix, and a basis is given by the identity together with the projection operator from $k^n$ to its trivial subrepresentation, namely the matrix

$$\left[ \begin{array}{cccc} \frac{1}{n} & \frac{1}{n} & \cdots & \frac{1}{n} \\
 \frac{1}{n} & \frac{1}{n} & \cdots & \frac{1}{n} \\
 \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
 \frac{1}{n} & \frac{1}{n} & \cdots & \frac{1}{n} \end{array} \right].$$

This matrix can be thought of as obtained by averaging together every permutation matrix.

An alternative and maybe more conceptual argument can also be used here involving [Hecke operators](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2015/11/07/hecke-operators-are-also-relative-positions/), which avoids Schur's lemma or needing to know anything about irreducibility.

Comment: First of all thank you for taking time your answer! Sadly I think that it goes way above my head since I am only familiar with the basics of group theory. I am also not really sure how would obtain information about the matrix entries in such a way. But I think it might be good to have $\forall i,j x_i \neq x_j$ as a restriction since for me only the matrices that manage to provide this property when every swap has an effect are really interesting. 
I thought using this restriction one could maybe say $det(A \cdot \pi_{i,j} - \pi_{i,j} \cdot A) = 0$

Comment: @elson1608: a more elementary argument is also possible. A matrix commutes with every permutation matrix iff it commutes with every transposition and you can just write down exactly what conditions on the entries this implies for every transposition. That should get you the answer pretty directly. The representation theory stuff is more sophisticated but shows that the answer can be obtained in a fairly mechanical way without any clever thinking.

Comment: In any case, the argument shows that there really aren't any "interesting" matrices with this property. The identity matrix obviously has it and so does the above matrix and you only get linear combinations of these.

Comment: For the two dimensional case I get: $det(A \cdot \pi_{i,j} - \pi_{i,j} \cdot A) = 0$ $a^2 - 2 a d - b^2 + 2 b c - c^2 + d^2 = 0$ and this where im stuck. I think there should be a way to get a = d and b = c but i don’t know how

Comment: @elson1608: you don't need to take determinants. I assume $\pi_{i, j}$ is the transposition $(ij)$; just write down what the condition $A \pi_{i, j} = \pi_{i, j} A$ says directly in terms of the coefficients of $A$.

Comment: Yeah I also just realized that and got it for two dimensions I’ll see what I get for 3 tomorrow